# Proof an equivalence of variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, sample-size

Given a sample of size N, how can you prove this?

$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}(x_{k}-\bar{x})^{2} = \frac{1}{2N^{2}}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\sum_{l = 1, l \neq k}^{N}(x_{k}-x_{l})^{2}$

So far I have:
$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}(x_{k}-\bar{x})^{2} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}(x_{k}-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{l = 1}^{N}x_{l})^{2} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}((\frac{N-1}{N})x_{k}-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{l = 1, l \neq k}^{N}x_{l})^{2}$$

Any hint?

Comment: In your first step, you've lost the $1/N$ from the mean

Comment: $$\text{var}(X_1)=\dfrac{1}{2}\text{var}(X_1-X_2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiest to start with the U-statistic form

First, put back the $k=l$ terms
$$\frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_{k\neq l} (x_k-x_l)^2 = \frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_{k,l=1}^N (x_k-x_l)^2$$
Now, introduce $\bar x$
$$ \frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_{k,l=1}^N (x_k-x_l)^2= \frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_{k,l=1}^N (x_k-\bar x+\bar x- x_l)^2$$
giving
$$ \frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_{k,l=1}^N (x_k-\bar x)^2+(\bar x-x_l)^2-2(x_k-\bar x)(\bar x-x_l)$$
The first two terms are what we want, so we just need to show the last term vanishes.

The last term is
$$\sum_{k,l} (x_k-\bar x)(\bar x-x_l)=\sum_k \left((x_k-\bar x)\sum_l (\bar x-x_l)\right)$$
The inner sum doesn't depend on $k$ and is identically zero, so the whole thing is zero.